# Is this code with PDO good (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PHP and I've followed a few tutorials on PDO after learning the basics of the language and I was just wondering if my code here is correct and what you guys'd suggest I can change to make it more secure, faster, more efficient, you name it...

I've followed numerous tutorials to achieve this result and therefore I thought I'd ask you guys as not every tutorial on the web on PHP (there are so many) are reliable sources to learn best practices and writing good code.

Here's the code I have. It only inserts the string 'Bill Gates' to the database, called 'pdotest', table 'tableOne' and row 'rowOne'. I've used persistent db connection because that's supposed to make the web application faster. I'm sure you guys can enlighten me on how to use this persistent connection thing correctly, I may have not fully understood how to use this in my code.

```
<?php

// DB connect configuration
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'password';

// Database connection
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdotest', $user, $pass, array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
    ));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    $conn = null;
    die();
}

// Data to insert (Bill Gates = Hero #1)
$data = 'Bill Gates';

try {
    // The insert query
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tableone (rowOne) VALUES (:rowOne)";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':rowOne'=>$data));   

    // Example INSERT query with multiple VALUES
    // $q->execute(array(':rowOne'=>$data, ':rowTwo'=>$dataTwo));   
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    $conn = null;
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is apparently inefficient as your PHP have to run twice more code than needed.
the below code is enough

```
 <?php

// DB connect configuration
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'password';
// Database connection
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdotest;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$data = 'Bill Gates';

$sql = "INSERT INTO tableone (rowOne) VALUES (?)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($data));
```

some highlights

- use persistent connection only if you certainly know what are you doing
- set exception mode if you are expecting exceptions
- DO NOT catch them only to die. PHP can die all right by itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the script! It really cleaned up my code.

 - 1) Could you explain a little bit about the persistent connection, why do I need to know what I'm doing?

 - 2) At school, I've learned always to do exception handling (with Java though). Why should or shouldn't I use exception handling?

 - 3) Thank you for this point. So PHP does die() by itself when needed? So it's unnecessary to use?

Comment: Persistent connection can do much more harm than good. You aren't actually handling your exceptions but rather just killing your script. For such a scenario PHP will handle uncaught exception in a way more elegant way, providing you with more info and browser with proper HTTP response code.

Comment: Hi Your Common Sense, your code inserts the value twice. When I insert the string 'Bill Gates' or whatever, it inserts two rows.

Comment: It's something with your own code. check HTTP requests your browser does

Comment: What in my code? I only use the code you gave me. In my previous code this didn't happen and I can't see anything that's not right with your code.