# PHP PDO INSERT query running twice

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've got this code with PHP PDO and I've got an INSERT query that runs twice. This code should insert the value 'Hello World' into the database. However, my code inserts the value twice into the database.

How do I fix this? I've stumbled upon other people with the same problem, but they have problems with a loop or they've used the explode function that messed something up. I don't have any of that, just one connection block and an insert query, and yet it does this weird thing.

The code:

```
// DB connect configuration
$user = 'user';
$pass = 'password';

// Database connection
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdotest;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);

$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

// Data to insert
$data = 'Test and test and test';

// Insert data into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabletwo (rowTwo) VALUES (?)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($data));
```

Comment: PDO won't do this by itself. Something is running your script twice, you need to figure out why that's happening.

Comment: is this the only code u have on this page ?

Comment: Why the new question? Just edit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22511859/is-this-code-with-pdo-good-php) one.

Comment: Yes Abhik, this is everything. There's just some HTML, that's it. I've included this file as follows: include(__DIR__ . '/../scrapll_m_nonstatic/init/db/connect.php');

Comment: In my experience, these problems tend to happen between the chair and the monitor. Scour your code for anything causing the query to run twice, check your includes, everything!

Comment: Hey danielsmile, I've found the problem I think. When I run this php code directly by entering it's location directly in the URL bar, everything goes fine and it inserts the data once. However, when I include this script on the index.php page, this problem occurs. I call this script with require_once(__DIR__ . '/../scrapll_m_nonstatic/init/db/connect.php');. With the include function the same thing happened too.

Comment: Chances are, you've also got some code in your include file that is causing this to happen. I saw in your other post that you are new to PHP, a normal connect.php file would only normally contain a new PDO, that all other pages can include, instead of writing it down on each page.

Comment: I now have the connection code in a connect.php file (outside the webroot folder) and I execute the insert query on the index.php file (and I include connect.php on index.php) and it does the same thing again.

Comment: Anyone else knows how to fix this?

Comment: Do you use Chrome/Safari to test this? My guess it that `index.php` file is actually executed twice - and that's quite easy to check in your webserver's logs.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because of some Javascript code for page transitions. The code can be found here: http://www.fasw.ws/faswwp/non-jquery-page-transitions-lightweight/. I have no idea how to fix this though.